# Property returns false if it couldn't update a variable

Tags: delphi

I understand the purpose of using properties in Delphi and my code is working fine, but I wonder if there is any possibility, that my property returns a boolean if it couldn't update a value, because the new value hasn't the correct format, for example:

A client wants to enter a username and the propertry tries to update it, but the class itself or better to say the setter only allows usernames that are longer than 3 characters. The propertry recognizes this problem and returns false, because it couldn't update the variable.

Code example:

```
TPlayer = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FUsername : String;
  private
    procedure SetUsername(const Username : String);
    function GetUsername() : String;
  public
    property Username : String read GetUsername write SetUsername;
end;

procedure TPlayer.SetUsername(const Username : String);
begin
  if length(Username) > 3 then
    begin
      Self.FUsername := Username;
    end;
end;

function TPlayer.GetUsername() : String;
begin
  Result := Self.FUsername;
end;
```

Comment: The validation should be done at the UI-level. If the property setter detects an invalid setting, raise an exception.

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan said, you should raise an exception: `if Username.Length > 3 then FUserName := UserName else raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid user name "%s". A user name must consist of at least four characters.', [UserName])`.

Comment: Also, please note that the phrase "property returns a boolean" doesn't even make sense, since a property doesn't "return" anything. A property can be read and/or set, and now we are talking about setting. The setter is a procedure, and procedures cannot return values.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I know that a property and a procedure can't return anything. I simply didnt know how to explain my problem otheriwse :D And thanks for your solution! It is nearly the same as mine, but I like yours a bit more :) Thank you

Comment: Note that you don't write `raise Exception.Create...` in real code, you always raise an exception class that is derived from `Exception` or derived from a sub-class of `Exception`.